# Different way to pass query string value through URL to ActionResult Method using ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, query-string

I am passing query string value mailer url to an action method.

I am passing like below URL to my activation `ActionResult`.

```
body += "Please click <a href=" + LinkPath + "Registers/Activation?emailId=" + emailid + "&uCode=" + activationCodes + "&type=" + a + ">here</a> to active your account" + "<br><br>";
```

Simple can I pass query string value to action method like below. Activation is my action method:

```
www.xyz.com/Registers/Activation?emailId=mazharkhan@gmail.com&uCode=12458475
```

Also I am getting a query string value in my `Activation` method like below

```
Request.QueryString["emailId"].ToString();
```

Actually my previous expriece with asp.net web forms now I am working using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework.

My question is it is fine to pass query string value like web form in my mailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter primitives are passed in the URL for a `GET` request.

MVC map the query string parameters to the method parameters for you through model binding. So you can write simply your `Controller` and your `Action` like this:

```
public class YourController: Controller
{
    [Route("Registers/Activation")]
    public ActionResult Get(string emailId, string codeType, string type)
    {
    }
}
```

Using `Request.QueryString` works but this is wrong in terms of how it should be done within MVC.

Comment: what is wrong with my query string url and explain that also. @Thierry V

Comment: sending parameters is fine na like : www.xyz.com/Registers/Activation?emailId=mazharkhan@gmail.com&uCode=12458475 and recieving parameters I udnerstood we should not use like Request.QueryString. @Thierry V